# JBOSS EAP 7.1.0 - Unsure of Logging and if it is a Out Of Memory Message.

Tags: jboss, java, redhat-openjdk

I got a note a from one of our application teams about some log entries after updating to JBOSS EAP 7.1.0 Domain mode from EAP 7.0.11. They're claiming it is a sign that the Application or JBOSS is running out of memory. I have checked everything on the server itself and it seems fine, no errors, other applications are working as designed. I also checked for custom logging and didn't see anything in the profile other then default loggers.  I Didn't really see anything on the Internet or in the JBOSS books about this entry so I figured I would ask since this still a pretty new release.  Thanks in Advance for the help!

- RHEL 7.4
- JBOSS EAP 7.1.0
- OpenJDK 1.8.0_151

This is an example of the log messages:

```
2018-01-23 08:19:36,094 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) free memory: 8,121 allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 3.368  
2018-01-23 08:19:43,995 INFO  [stdout] (default task-26) free memory: 5,368 allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 2.226  
2018-01-23 08:19:48,347 INFO  [stdout] (default task-31) free memory: 2,668 allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 1.107  
2018-01-23 08:24:41,693 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) free memory: 1,947  allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 0.808  
2018-01-23 08:29:27,092 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) free memory: 7,279  allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 3.019  
2018-01-23 08:29:34,759 INFO  [stdout] (default task-8) free memory: 3,944  allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 1.636  
2018-01-23 08:36:28,319 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) free memory: 3,585  allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 1.487  
2018-01-23 08:40:34,410 INFO  [stdout] (default task-27) free memory: 11,838    allocated memory: 241,152   percentage left: 4.909
```

Comment: Yeah, google shows nothing :-/ my only guess would be it's showing garbage collection trace? We're barely getting upgraded to JBoss EAP 7 so unfortunately I havent run into that before - though I have seen tomcat servers log that information.

Comment: That looks like a "System.out.println" somewhere ... you're sure that's not from your application code? I'd rather be suprised if JBoss would log something via STDOUT...

Comment: @tom , That was the argument I kept putting up to them as well. I truly think it's application based, I asked them to review the code yesterday.  Thanks for backing me up! :-)

Comment: When troubleshooting why the Out of memory (OOM) has been occurred one must look at a few factors on the system. Below reasons:
1# Spike in memory usage based on a load event (additional processes are needed for increased load).
2# Spike in memory usage based on additional services being added or migrated to the system. (Added another app or started a new service on the system)
3#Spike in memory usage due to failed hardware
4#Spike in memory usage due to undersizing of hardware resources for the running application(s).
5#There's a memory leak in a running application.